# Reload Kubernetes deployment to fetch new secret without downtime

Tags: deployment, kubernetes

In Kubernetes I have a Deployment that uses a secret and injects them as environment variables:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
...
envFrom:
  - secretRef:
    name: api-env
```

I need to update some of the environment variables, so I deleted the secret `api-env` and created it again with the updated values.

How do I trigger the deployment to update itself with the new env secrets without any downtime?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see a few alternatives, in order of viability:

1. For k8s' versions >v1.15: `kubectl rollout restart deployment $deploymentname`: this will
   restart pods incrementally without causing downtime.
2. For older versions: Updating the deployment template will trigger a rollout. From [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/13488#issuecomment-356892053): `kubectl patch deployment mydeployment -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"mycontainer","env":[{"name":"RESTART_","value":"'$(date +%s)'"}]}]}}}}'`
3. Mount secrets on volumes instead of as environment variables, as [Mounted Secrets are
   updated automatically](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/secrets/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod)
4. [One approach](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22368) is to consider the Secret/Configmap as immutable and when creating a new one changing the deployment to point to it.
5. Program your application to watch for changes in the [Secrets API](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/rest_api/api/v1.Secret.html#Get-api-v1-watch-namespaces-namespace-secrets-name).

Comment: I spoke to soon. It seems `rollout restart` is not a valid Kubernetes command.

Comment: What is your k8s' version? If I am not mistaken this feature was introduced on v1.15

Comment: Running on Amazon EKS, 1.13. That's the latest version they support.

Comment: I have added a new alternative similar to the first one using `patch`. Also, besides `patch` it would be nice if you could test if `set env` also triggers a rollout:  `kubectl set env deployment --env="RESTART=$(date +%s)"  $deploymentname`